# Regex: captures, groups, confusion

Tags: .net, regex

I can't seem to figure out captures + groups in Regex (.net).

Let's say I have the following input string, where each letter is actually a placeholder for more complex regex expression (so simple character exclusion won't work):

```
CBDAEDBCEFBCD
```

Or, more generically, here is a string pattern written in 'regex':

```
(C|B|D)*A(E*)(D|B|C)*(E*)F(B|C|D)*
```

There will only be one A and one F.
I need to capture as individual 'captures' (or matches or groups) all instances of B, C, D (which in my app are more complex groups) that occur after A and before F. I also need A and F. I don't need E. And I don't need the C,B,D before the A or the B,C,D after the F.

I would expect the correct result to be:

```
Groups["start"] (1 capture) = A
Groups["content"] (3 captures)  
  Captures[0] = D  
  Captures[1] = B
  Captures[2] = C
Groups["end"] (1 capture) = F
```

I tried a few feeble attempts but none of them worked.

Only "incorrectly" captures the last C before EF in the sample string above (as well as correctly start = A, end = F)

```
(?<=(?<start>A)).+(?<content>B|C|D).+(?=(?<end>F))
```

Same results as above (just added a + after (?B|C|D) )

```
(?<=(?<start>A)).+(?<content>B|C|D)+.+(?=(?<end>F))
```

Got rid of look-around stuff... same result as above

```
(?<start>A).+(?<content>B|C|D)+.+(?<end>F)
```

And then my good-for-nothing brain went on strike.

So, what's the right way to approach this? Are look-arounds really needed for this or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, forget the lookarounds, they just complicate things needlessly.  But I suspect your final regex will work if you make that first `.+` reluctant:

```
(?<start>A).+?(?<content>B|C|D)+.+(?<end>F)
```

EDIT: *yep*:

```
string s = "CBDAEDBCEFBCD";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<start>A).+?(?<content>B|C|D)+.+(?<end>F)");

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s))
{
  Console.WriteLine(@"Groups[""start""] = {0}", m.Groups["start"]);
  foreach (Capture c in m.Groups["content"].Captures)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(@"Capture[""content""] = {0}", c.Value);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(@"Groups[""end""] = {0}", m.Groups["end"]);
}
```

output:

```
Groups["start"] = A
Capture["content"] = D
Capture["content"] = B
Capture["content"] = C
Groups["end"] = F
```

Comment: Really! So lookarounds are not needed huh... amazing.

Comment: @Jimmy: In this case, yes, lookarounds are not needed.  But they do have their uses. :P

Answer (score 0):

Since you said all instance of `C,B,D`, I would think you'd want to use a grouping for that `[CBD]*`  Also, if you're just looking for something to be after the letter `A` but before `F`, then you should be able to use those literals along with some exclusions.

Here's a pattern I came up with.  Group `$4` should contain the letter `DBC`

```
([^A]*)(A)([^CBDF]*)([CBD]*)([^F]*)(F)(.*)
```

Here's an example of [this pattern in action](http://regexr.com?2s8pv).

The question is, what do you want if the original string is `CBDAEDEBECEFBCD`?

Comment: Sorry, all the letters are place holders for more complex groups (I'll update the question) - so I can't just use literal exclusions. The string CBDAEDEBECEFBCD you suggest shouldn't match at all -- there's just a bunch of E's between A and the first (B|C|D), and a bunch of E's immediately before the F. Again, in my app, they're not just E's, they're just text that I don't need.

Comment: If that's the case, then look-arounds are probably your only option.

Comment: Are you able to suggest a look around that works? Even with look arounds I still can't get it to work.